# WebInspector crashed in Safari 7

Tags: safari, osx-mavericks, web-inspector

When I try to display web inspector just a grey background shows instead of that. I tried to restart browser but it didn't help. It happens in Safary 7 OS X Mavericks.

Anybody knows what is that could be?

Comment: Try http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Resizing of the window or web inspector helps to display WI content. But the problem happen all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (works permanent, without reboot):

Open Terminal:
`killall -KILL Dock`

This is Dock restart.

EDIT:

Also you can make alias in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, for fast run of this cmd.

`alias dockrestart="killall -KILL Dock"`